IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF, Can't Connect with SSMS SQL server in a .NET Version 8 Code
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Books' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.b__211_0(Task1 result) at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask2.InnerInvoke()
Can't insert the values in the Database Table through the code.
But when I'm using SSMS directly Insert operation works, and for that I've to use
SET IDENTITY INSERT {TABLE_NAME} ON.
Unable to use POST Request in API.
I want a solution so that it won't ask for Identity Insert to turn on again and again.

don't put value to IDENTITY column. It will be automatically generated.

@SainPradeep, there may be reasons that you need to insert IDs into identity columns. For example, the code in my answer comes from a data migration project, where we were importing data from an existing database into a new one and we wanted to retain existing IDs but also have them generated automatically for new records.

Here's an example from a recent data migration project of my own:
dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"SET IDENTITY_INSERT {nameof(MarineParkZone)} ON");
dbContext.SaveChanges();
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"SET IDENTITY_INSERT {nameof(MarineParkZone)} OFF");
dbContext.Database.CommitTransaction();

You might put those five lines in a method that took the table name and the DbContext as argumnents, allowing you to do it for any table with a single method call. If there might be multiple tables being saved then you might do this:
private void SaveData(DbContext dbContext, params string[] idInsertTableNames)
{
    dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();

    foreach (var tableName in idInsertTableNames)
    {
        dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"SET IDENTITY_INSERT {tableName} ON");
    }

    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    foreach (var tableName in idInsertTableNames)
    {
        dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"SET IDENTITY_INSERT {tableName} OFF");
    }

    dbContext.Database.CommitTransaction();
}

You could then call that with zero, one or more tables specified:
SaveData(dbContext);
SaveData(dbContext, "Table1");
SaveData(dbContext, "Table1", "Table2");

Here's part of the setup for EF:
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection().AddDbContext<EyeOnTheReefDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(destinationConnectionString,
                                                                                                                    providerOptions =>
                                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                                        // EnableRetryOnFailure cannot be used because we require a transaction to set IDENTITY_INSERT.
                                                                                                                        //providerOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                                                                                                                        providerOptions.UseNetTopologySuite();
                                                                                                                    }));

Note the comment:

EnableRetryOnFailure cannot be used because we require a transaction to set IDENTITY_INSERT.

